# Equation of the Center constant factor

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

This questions concerns the longitudinal aspect of the Equation of Time, also called the Equation of the Center. In some sources the equation looks like the following:

$\nu - M = 2\varepsilon \sin M$       (1)

where $\nu$ is the True Anomaly of the Sun's position from the Earth, $M$ is the Mean Anomaly, and $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity of the Earth's orbit (0.0167). $\nu - M$ is the difference between the Sun's actual angle and the and the angle that would exist if the Earth's orbit were circular.

Other sources have a first-order approximation that looks like the following:

Time deviation (minutes) = $-7.655 \sin d$       (2)

where d is the day of the year.

My difficulty is reconciling these two equations. None of the sources actually make this connection explicit. I assume that the difference has to do with converting angles and times, and I have tried various approaches to making the numbers work out, without avail. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how the value of -7.655 minutes is derivable from $2 \varepsilon$ and or point me at a resource that demonstrates the connection between them.

(Note I realize that both (1) and (2) are approximations. At this stage, I am trying to understand the situation in its simplest form before adding refinements.

Comment: I edited your post to use TeX. Please confirm I haven't changed the meaning, thanks!

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) you must convert minutes to radians, 2) you must convert sin(days) to sin(radians), possibly using the product rule for sines.

Comment: The conversion to LaTex looks good. Thanks for making it. BTW, is there an easy way to include Mathematica equations?

Comment: Update: The conversion to LaTex looks good, if d in (2) is taken to mean ((d/365.24)*(2Pi)). Thanks for making it. BTW, is there an easy way to include Mathematica equations?

Comment: Mathematica has a "TeXForm" you could use. After converting to TeXForm, put the result between two dollar signs.

Comment: Note that one hour = 15 degrees, so 7.655 minutes equals 7.655*15/60 or 1.91375 degrees. When you divide this by twice the eccentricity, you get 1.91375/(2*0.0167) = 57.2979041916 which is approximately the number of degrees in a radian. Not sure if this helps at all, just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete answer, but I do know where the $7.6$ factor comes from: It equals
$$(2×0.0167)×(24×60)/(2 \pi).$$

$0.0167$ comes from the eccentricity of the Earth, and the factor of $2$ comes from the above equation. $24×60$ converts from days to minutes, and $2 \pi$ is the number of radians in a complete revolution.

What I still don't completely understand is why these coordinate conversions need to be done, specifically the division by $2 \pi$.

Thanks everyone for your help.

**Edit:** I now have a somewhat better explanation for the computation in this answer. `2ε sin(M)` is the number of radians that the mean Sun is behind the apparent Sun on Noon on a day with mean anomaly `M`. Dividing the `2ε` factor by `2π`gives the fraction of the rotation *of the Earth* (i.e. one day). When the result is multiplied by the number of minutes in a *sidereal* day `(23×60+54)` yields the desired coefficient `7.63345`.